# How to break loop in shell script used to truncate table?

Tags: shell, ksh, sqlcmd

I'm writing a script truncating tables. The problem is that the script goes in infinite loop.

`./n_input` contains environment variables that are used in script.

```
#!/bin/ksh

INPUT_FILE=./n_input
if [ ! -e $INPUT_FILE ];
then
        echo "Error: Input file require"
        exit 1
fi

source $INPUT_FILE

while read Table
do
        TABLE="$DSTN_DATABASE.dbo.$Table"

        echo "Table : $TABLE"

        QUERY="truncate table $TABLE"
        echo $QUERY > ./tmp_file
        sqlcmd -m 1 -U $DSTN_USER -P $DSTN_PASSWORD -D -S $DSTN_SERVER -m1 -i ./tmp_file

        RET_VALUE=$?
        if [ $RET_VALUE -ne 0 ]
        then
           echo "Error $TABLE"
        fi
done < $TABLE_LIST
exit 0
```

How do I break the loop? I have tried to remove `sqlcmd` from script and verified that it was working. It's working as expected. Observed the same behavior with `sqlcmd -Q` option.

`$TABLE_LIST` file contains only one table name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to write the query into temporary file. Use `-q`, or `-Q` options instead:

```
q="truncate table ${TABLE};"
sqlcmd -m 1 -U "$DSTN_USER" -P "$DSTN_PASSWORD" -S "$DSTN_SERVER" -q "$q"
```

Note the `;` at the end of the query. Probably, that's the reason why the script "stalls". That may look like an infinitely running loop.

Also note the use of double quotes. You should wrap variables in double quotes to prevent reinterpretation of the special characters.

By the way, you can locate the exact command that is causing the issue by adding `set -x` at the beginning of the script. `set -x` turns on debugging mode. With debugging mode on, you see the commands being executed.

It's very unlikely that the content of `$TABLE_LIST` file is causing such behavior, unless the file is enormously big. The loop construct is correct, and the number of iterations should match the number of lines in the file.

Comment: thanks for edit and answer... problem is with sqlcmd... sqlcmd wait for input and while goes in infinite look.. resolved issue by passing EOF to sqlcmd as `sqlcmd  -U $DSTN_USER -P $DSTN_PASSWORD -D -S $DSTN_SERVER <<-EOF \n $QUERY \n go \n EOF`
`

Comment: @Pravin, "_sqlcmd wait for input and while goes in infinite_" - that's what I meant. But, I guess, appending `;`, or `;go;` to the query should be enough. However, the docs recommend to not use the `go` terminator in the query. So a single `;` should fix the issue. Have you tried to append a semicolon?